# Graphical tool to search Subversion revisions of a file

Tags: gratis, search, subversion

I deleted an unused function from my code some time ago, and now I would like to add it back in again.

The check-in history does not help me. is there any tool, with a GUI, which I can use to search through all previous versions of a given file (a single file in this case, but multiple is welcome) for a given text?

It would be nice to show the file contents, maybe with some search/edit capabilities, but just the revision number is enough.

Gratis. Must be free for commercial use. Either Windows or Linux is OK.

Comment: How graphical is graphical? What must be there to help you except entering the search term?

Comment: Until someone answers: something like `svn log -v --xml --diff <file>` should result in a file that can be searched for the wanted difference.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever tried [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/)? It allows you to use "Blame" on a file to see previous versions of the file and highlight changes. It's free, but it is only for Windows.

UPDATE:
For a full blown text search, I found something called [SVNQuery](http://svnquery.tigris.org/). I have never used it, but I found a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254214/svn-repository-search) on Stack Overflow that looks like it might be similar to yours.

Comment: Well, https://tortoisesvn.net/blame.html says "TortoiseBlame - who changed which line, when and why?", so it won't let me search for a given text :-( BUT, +1 for a very helpful

Comment: Thank you. I added an update to my answer. Hopefully it will be more help more with your problem :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for some text in the files past that information will only be available in to the server rather than locally - so access will be slow.

You could however use [git as an svn client](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) to download a git repository of your project, *this will take some time but believe me it will save it as well* and then from the command line you can use `git grep` to find any text in the history either for the whole repository or a single file.

There is also a built in GUI `gitk` or a large number of 3rd party GUI tools that include the capability to search the entire history of a single file or the whole repository. The GUI also lets you view the file with changes as unified diffs.

Git and gitk are available, free, for just about every platform.

[image]